# Anet A8 stops printing

Tags: ultimaker-cura, anet-a8, troubleshooting, print-failure, bug

I have an issue with my Anet A8 printer and how it interlocks with Ultimaker Cura.

I want to print this file named `Loki_hörner_v2.stl`and Cura slices it fine, but when it comes to printing all the preheat happens, but then it stops, not going on at all. What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special characters like `Ä` `Ö` or `Ü` in the stl-filename resulted in Ultimaker Cura creating a comment of the filename in the g-code that read like

```
;MESH:Loki_hörner_v2.stl
```

This apparently could not be parsed by the Anet A8, leading to an error and halt.

Comment: It's great that you found and shared the answer. Did you get it to work by removing the character with umlauts?

Comment: @Davo yes, after removing/replacing the umlaut in the stl-filename, reslicing it, it works. (i did not test to manually remove the umlauts from the gcode manually, but I have a strong believe that this would work too)

Answer (score 4):

#### Avoid naming `.gcode` files with non-ASCII characters

*(this includes [EASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII))*

I know of no firmware on a printer that can handle files that have characters not present in the set of 95 non-control [American Standard Code for Information Interchange characters](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp) by default. Marlin, for example, can't process the characters `ä` `ö` `ü` & `€` as these all are missing in the ASCII.

#### Avoid having more than one `.`

Nowadays the `.` is no longer a fully reserved character in file names, so a file can be named `0.5mm Gauge Block.stl` on Windows without problems.

Ultimaker Cura will **cut** the name at the `.` before the extension when generating the `.gcode`. This is mainly done to prevent tons of errors that could crop up in firmware that might not be able to deal with it. Remember that this behavior can lead to overwriting files - our `0.5mm Gauge Block.stl` would generate `0.gcode`, as would `0.1.5 Penholder.stl` (that follows a version naming convention).

#### Avoid reserved characters

Also note that some characters are reserved in file naming and will lead to other errors (mainly when trying to create the files in the first place), including, but not limited to, `/` `\` `:` `?` `*`.

Comment: Agreed - I always convert "my_part_reduce0.5" to "my_part_reduce0p5" for that reason.